# Axios.Delete() not executing then neither catch block

Tags: c#, reactjs, axios

I have react + redux client and C# API. I am currently trying to implement the delete method in react.

**patients.js**

```
deletePatient(patientId) {
    debugger;
    axios.delete(url + 'patients/' + patientId).then(res => 
    {      
        this.props.dispatch(deletePatientAction(res));
    })
    .catch( function(error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
    });
}
```

**PatientController.cs**

```
[HttpDelete]
    public HttpResponseMessage Delete(int id)
    {
        patientTasks.Delete(id);

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

when I debug it in chrome I can see that then and catch block is not executed. The request is not being caught on my C# controller.

When I try the same request with Postman, the request is being caught in API normally.

This does not work even if I put the url as a hardcoded string 
`axios.delete('http://localhost:1467/v1/patients/11')`

Can you please tell me what is happening (not happening)?

note: get methods are working properly

Comment: Does it work if you run the same request with postman ?

Comment: yes, I told it in my question.

Comment: sorry I read too fast... What do you see in the Chrome network inspector ?

Comment: any new record in network when I step by axios call

Comment: Does the console show any errors?

Comment: no it does not. when I step on this line `axios.delete(url + 'patients/' + patientId)` and then step over it jump on the end of the catch block and then jumping out of the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the huge thanks to my friend I am posting the working solution. I was missing the default headers. Postman is by inserting default headers, with `axios` I have to define it by myself.

```
deletePatient(patientId) {
        var config = {
            headers: {
                'User-Agent':'',
                'Accept':'',
                'Host':''
            }
        };

        axios.delete(url + 'patients/' + patientId, config).then((res) => 
        {      
            this.props.dispatch(deletePatientAction(res));
        })
        .catch( function(error) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
        });            
}
```